# How to get windows user name in vue.js using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

var userName = process.env["USERPROFILE"];
console.log(userName);

library.add(fas);
Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

its showing undefined for "userName"..this is a vue js app but is there any way i could use this to work

Answer (score 0):

nodejs

```
const os = require('os')
const username = os.userInfo().username
console.log(username)
```

[getUserName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZluj.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).